# Exporting each layer in map to separate image using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layers, export

I have a mxd file with multiple layers I have to export to PNG/JPG. I would like to create a script which turns on layers one at the time before they are exported. So far I have come up with the following:

```
import arcpy, string

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")

#Read input parameters from script tool
LyrList = string.split.(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")

PNGPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Turn of all lyrs in list
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, LyrList):
    lyr.visible = False


#Turn on lyr and export as png one by one
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, LyrList):
    lyr.visible = True
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, PNGPath+"\\" + lyr.name + ".png")
    lyr.visible = False

del LyrList
del mxd
```

For the LyrList I use a dialoge box with the parameter data-type as Layer.
Does anyone have an idea how to get this script working? When I use the ListLayers wildcard the script does work, but since I have a lot of layerfiles which all hace a kind of unique name that does not do the job for me.

Comment: Did you get an error?  What about the script isn't working?

Comment: I do get an error if I execute the script like it is written here above. The error I get is: "<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (ExportLYRsToPNG.py, line 6)" 

When I change line 6 into: "LyrList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) "
I do not get an error, but there are no png's exported.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by printing `LyrList` to see what the specific problem is?
Is this for your own purposes or for someone else?  I ask because you could do this without creating a script tool;  see if it works by creating your own list as opposed to `GetParameterAsText`.

Comment: I have printed the LyrList and all the lyr-files do get in the LyrList so that's not the problem. But they cannot be used in the way I am trying?

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  Rather than identifying your layers as a wildcard, you can test that the layer name is equal to the current layer in your loop, if TRUE then you change visibility and export as a .png.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0] # assuming there is only 1 df you're interested in

#Read input parameters from script tool
allLayers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # Must be a multivalue in script tool params
lyrList = allLayers.split(";")

PNGPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Turn of all lyrs in list
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
    for layer in lyrList:
        if lyr.name == layer:
            lyr.visible = False
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

# Loop through each layer, turn it on and export map as PNG
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
    for layer in lyrList:
        if lyr.name == layer:
            lyr.visible = True
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView() # May want to test without this -- ArcMap might export correctly without need for refresh active view
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, PNGPath+"\\" + lyr.name + ".png")
            lyr.visible = False
```

Comment: I have tried to make your solution work, it is indeed 1 df I'm interested in. Unfortunately I still get an error in line 13 of the script. The error which is returning in the dialog is "<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (ExportLYRsToPNG.py, line 13)"

Comment: For line 13 I have put an extra '='between lyr.name and LyrList and then I don't get the error on line 13. But an entire new one: 'module' object has no attribute 'ListDataFrame'.

Comment: it's a syntax error, should be `arcpy.ListDataFrames`

Comment: I see... That was very sloppy from me I should have seen that. For now I still get an indexerror: "<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>: list index out of range" I have double-checked and have searched on the internet for it, but I cannot find a sollution.

Comment: See updated script.  My mistake I created a script that worked for me, but not all use cases last time.  As I say in the script comment, the `arcpy.RefreshActiveView` may be unneccessary (try without it to see if the map exports correctly).  If it's not needed things will run faster.

Comment: Hello Roy,

I have tried your last version of your edits, with and without the RefreshActiveView the script gets stuck in a loop or something. I don't get an error, but ArcGIS is not responding anymore. Do you have any suggestions how this could be resolved?

Comment: Since the loop is only looping through layers in the map / in the list it's definitely not an infinite loop.  Using this code I was able to turn off all layers in my mxd.

Comment: I figured out why it didn't work for me, because I used grouplayers and also used spaces in the names of the lyrfiles. Is there any way to resolve this matter, because I need to use spaces in the lyr-name.

Comment: Couldn't you just use underscores instead of spaces?

Comment: I could use underscores, but then these underscores appear in the legend as well, which is not prefered. Therefor I was searching for an alternative.

Comment: File names can't have spaces, but aliases can.  Avoid the spaces in your file names and rename them in your table of contents.  You can chance the alias manually if it's not a huge number of files.

If you're using ArcGIS 10.1 there's an arcpy function to automate the process. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000008v000000