# Export Query Layer to shapefile using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, export, error-999999, query-layer, error-000210

Composing a map using query layers in ArcGIS 10.4.1 (Basic) the final step is to backup the data used when the map is finalised.
Exporting manually is [straight forward](http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/exporting-features.htm). 
But using the conversion tool results in ERROR 999999.
Using arcpy as elaborated in https://geonet.esri.com/thread/66389#comment-303614 produces on the help and syntax window in short:
*ERROR 000210: (...) No support for this geometry type. Error executing FeatureClassToFeatureClass (...)*.
(in original:
Ausführung von: FeatureClassToFeatureClass GPL0 D:\test "name of the layer".shp # "CITY "CITY" true true false 100 Text 0 0 ,First,#,GPL0,CITY,-1,-1" #
Startzeit: Tue Jan 17 07:25:20 2017
ERROR 000210: Ausgabe D:\test\"name of the layer".shp kann nicht erstellt werden.
No support for this geometry type.
Fehler beim Ausführen von (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
Fehlgeschlagen am Tue Jan 17 07:25:20 2017 (Verstrichene Zeit: 0,02 Sekunden)
)
the primary prompt shows:
*Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 5, in    File "c:\software\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1694, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Ausgabe D:\test\"name of the layer".shp kann nicht erstellt werden. Fehler beim Ausführen von (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).*

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layer")[0]
count = 0 
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
  if count < 20:
    count +=1
    name = lyr.name
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(lyr, r"D:\test", name + ".shp")
```

Querying for the geometry type via:
    select distinct a.geom.SDO_GTYPE from "name of the original table" a 
results in: 2001 (The 2 indicates two-dimensional, and the 1 indicates a single point.)

A successful export not explicitly for query layers is also discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109986/how-to-export-all-the-layers-from-table-of-content-to-shp-file). [Checking the layer properties source within ArcMap reveals the Data Type of Query Feature Class](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2014/04/08/the-evolution-of-query-layers/).

How would one be able to export then this type using arcpy?

Comment: What is the full error message including line number that you receive when running the precise code snippet that you have presented?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Export via arcpy is feasable using the [toolbox mechanism](http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/adding-a-script-tool.htm): when the code presented is deployed and executed that way, the wanted shapefiles are produced in folder D:\test.
Result message is:
*Ausführung von: export
Startzeit: Tue Jan 17 08:40:36 2017
Skript export wird ausgeführt...
Completed script export...
Erfolgreich am Tue Jan 17 08:40:36 2017 (Verstrichene Zeit: 0,06 Sekunden)*